# SQL Query Returning Only one row in result

Tags: php, mysql, json, mysqli

I am getting only one row for result of my query. I need get three result but its showing only one row in result. I have tried to change code as much as possible but its not showing more then one row in result. My code is like below.

```
elseif($module=="winners")
{

         $result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM `contest` WHERE showresult=1");
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {

         $result = mysqli_query($conn,"select * FROM `contest_score` order by score desc, CAST(timequiz as DECIMAL(9,2)) ASC limit 0,3");
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {

    $response["scores"] = array();

    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $scores = array();
            $scores["id"] = $row["id"];
            $scores["user_id"] = $row["user_id"];
            $scores["username"] = $row["username"];
            $scores["score"] = $row["score"];
            $scores["played_date"] = $row["played_date"];
            $scores["timequiz"] = $row["timequiz"];
            $user_id = $row["user_id"];
            $result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT user_image FROM `users` WHERE id=$user_id");
            $temp_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

            $scores["user_image"] = $temp_row["user_image"];

          array_push($response["scores"], $scores);
          }
           $response["success"] = 1;

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
```

Please check and let me know if someone can help me for solve my issue.

Thanks

Comment: i think u should echo inside the WHILE to loop the data inside ur database.

Comment: how do you know that this *query* returns only one row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might have something to do with it: you are re-writing your `$result` variable in the loop.

`$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT user_image FROM 'users' WHERE id=$user_id");`

Comment: Bingo. Reusing a variable